# Should I put my LocalBusiness schema on the home page or contact page?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, local-seo

As I understand Google don't need `LocalBusiness` or `Organization` schema on every page, and in fact need only on one page of the website. So my question is should it be put on home page or contact page? What is the difference, if any?

Answer (score 1):

**[Google is pretty clear](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies#relevance)**:

> **Relevance**
>
> Your structured data must be a true representation of the
> page content.

Therefore, it makes sense to set your structured data to represent a local business only for content that also represents a local business.

Comment: while the home page would represent a local business, the content on it do not contain all the services the business provide. in such case, should service details be listed in hasOfferCatalog within LocalBusiness schema where the page's content do not cover? ty

Comment: You can set the URL to the separate content of your services for this property, e.g.,  hasOfferCatalog -> OfferCatalog -> name+url

Comment: does it mean even if there're no service content on the main page that I could still put the details in hasOfferCatalog on the main page?

Comment: See my answer. The SD should represent the main content that is being referenced.

Comment: ok, got your point